# Простой парсер html

Tags: синтаксический-анализ, php, парсер, html, dom

Помогите найти простой парсер `html`, желательно с примером кода, надо получить код:
Первый див `class="quote"` на странице `http://xxx.ru`, в `div class="actions"`, парсится сначала `n` в атрибуте `<a class="id" href="/quote/n">`, потом на странице `m http://xxx.ru/m`, потом находится блок с див `class="quote"`, у котороо в диве `class="actions"`, есть необходимый `k <a class="id" href="/quote/k">` и парсится блок следующий за ним `div class="text"`.

Comment: Да спасибо, остановился на PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser,  я уже пробовал его использовать, но тогда что-то не получилось, а сейчас все ок.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону [phpquery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) или [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), думаю второй вариант будет более приемлем в вашем случае.

Comment: +1 в пользу PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser
Правда из всех известных мне парсеров, этот - самый тормознутый. Но у него есть огромное преимущество - он не отвалится, если документ HTML будет невалидный.
Советую еще на хабре порыться, там где-то была статья, сравнивающая разные парсеры

Answer (score 0):

Можете воспользоваться библиотекой [simple_html_dom](https://github.com/samacs/simple_html_dom). Там и примеры есть в папке example

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите к примеру на [это](http://habrahabr.ru/post/176635/). Там парсер с jQuery подобным синтаксисом (обычно, программист на php хоть краем уха его, а знает).

Answer (score 0):

[preg_math](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php)

[preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match-all.php)